# changing more than one divs simulteniously on an event in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

**I want to change attributes of two different imagaes (that are in two different divs) on mouseclick event. The code which i am using is below:**

```
<html onclick="show_coords(event)" style="cursor:crosshair">
<head>
<style>
div.div2
{
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
z-index:+1;
}
div.impact
{
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
z-index:+1;
}
</style>
<script>

function show_coords(e)
{
// var x=event.clientX;
// var y=event.clientY;

    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
            + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    // posx and posy contain the mouse position relative to the document
    // Do something with this information

--------------------------------Block 1-----------------------------------------

// This code is for changing div with id = "id2" and class as "div2"

var impact_gun = document.getElementsByClassName("div2");
 alert(impact_gun[0].id+" "+impact_gun[1].id);

// impact_gun[1] contains "id2"

  impact_gun[1].style.left = posx - 47 + 40 + "px";
  impact_gun[1].style.top = posy - 85 + 78 + "px";
 impact_gun[1].style.z-index='+1';

 alert(impact_gun[0]+" "+impact_gun[1]);

//--------------------------------Block 1------------------------------------------



//--------------------------------Block 2----------------------------------------- 

// This code is for changing div with id = "id1" and class as "div2"

var gun1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div2");
var impact_gun12 = document.getElementById(gun1[0].id);

// impact_gun12 contains "id1"
impact_gun12.style.transform = "skew(30deg,20deg)";
impact_gun12.style.webkitTransform = "skew(30deg,20deg)";
```

}

```
//--------------------------------Block 2----------------------------------------- 


</script>
</head>

<body>

//--------------------------------Div with id as "id1"----------------------------

<div id="id1" class="div2">
<img src="C:\Users\john\Desktop\gun2.gif" width="100" height="140" /> 
</div>

//--------------------------------Div with id as "id1"----------------------------



//--------------------------------Div with id as "id2"----------------------------

<div id="id2" class="div2">
<img src="C:\Users\john\Desktop\impact.png" width="15" height="15"
</div>

//--------------------------------Div with id as "id2"----------------------------

</body>
</html>

-----------------------------End of code--------------------------
```

**The problem is that only one block (either block 1 or block 2) executes and in this case it is block 1 that executes and if contents of block 1 is commented with "//" then block 2 executes.**

I want both blocks to be executed simultaneously on the click event which is not happening

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: 'show_coords' is undefined

Comment: could you please make a fiddle ?

Comment: there are just too many errors: *onclick on html*, *function show_coords* never ends, *z-index assignment*, *getElementsByClassName*...

Comment: The `onclick` should work, though, and I don't see any problem with `getElementsByClassName()`. I think the z-index assignment is the real issue here.

Comment: what i know is that only 1 block (either block 1 or block 2) is executing, everything else is working fine, its like it can use id only once and hence only one block is executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'll take a wild guess. This line of yours:

```
impact_gun[1].style.z-index='+1';
```

is wrong and the error stops the JavaScript execution there. It should be:

```
impact_gun[1].style.zIndex='1';
```